# plot pgfplots graph similar to facet_wrap from ggplot2

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I need to plot a 2x2 grid of graphs as shown below:

[image]

**Note:** The above graph was generated using the `ggplot2` library from the statistical programming language [R](http://www.r-project.org/).
Graph taken from [link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_%28ggplot2%29/).

Here are the four data files:

`tips-fri.csv`:

```
totalbill,tip,sex,smoker,day,time,size
28.97,3,Male,Yes,Fri,Dinner,2
22.49,3.5,Male,No,Fri,Dinner,2
5.75,1,Female,Yes,Fri,Dinner,2
16.32,4.3,Female,Yes,Fri,Dinner,2
22.75,3.25,Female,No,Fri,Dinner,2
40.17,4.73,Male,Yes,Fri,Dinner,4
27.28,4,Male,Yes,Fri,Dinner,2
12.03,1.5,Male,Yes,Fri,Dinner,2
21.01,3,Male,Yes,Fri,Dinner,2
12.46,1.5,Male,No,Fri,Dinner,2
11.35,2.5,Female,Yes,Fri,Dinner,2
15.38,3,Female,Yes,Fri,Dinner,2
12.16,2.2,Male,Yes,Fri,Lunch,2
13.42,3.48,Female,Yes,Fri,Lunch,2
8.58,1.92,Male,Yes,Fri,Lunch,1
15.98,3,Female,No,Fri,Lunch,3
13.42,1.58,Male,Yes,Fri,Lunch,2
16.27,2.5,Female,Yes,Fri,Lunch,2
10.09,2,Female,Yes,Fri,Lunch,2
```

`tips-sat.csv`:

```
totalbill,tip,sex,smoker,day,time,size
20.65,3.35,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,3
17.92,4.08,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
20.29,2.75,Female,No,Sat,Dinner,2
15.77,2.23,Female,No,Sat,Dinner,2
39.42,7.58,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,4
19.82,3.18,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
17.81,2.34,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,4
13.37,2,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
12.69,2,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
21.7,4.3,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
19.65,3,Female,No,Sat,Dinner,2
9.55,1.45,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
18.35,2.5,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,4
15.06,3,Female,No,Sat,Dinner,2
20.69,2.45,Female,No,Sat,Dinner,4
17.78,3.27,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
24.06,3.6,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,3
16.31,2,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,3
16.93,3.07,Female,No,Sat,Dinner,3
18.69,2.31,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,3
31.27,5,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,3
16.04,2.24,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,3
38.01,3,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,4
26.41,1.5,Female,No,Sat,Dinner,2
11.24,1.76,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
48.27,6.73,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,4
20.29,3.21,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
13.81,2,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
11.02,1.98,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
18.29,3.76,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,4
17.59,2.64,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,3
20.08,3.15,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,3
16.45,2.47,Female,No,Sat,Dinner,2
3.07,1,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,1
20.23,2.01,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
15.01,2.09,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
12.02,1.97,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
17.07,3,Female,No,Sat,Dinner,3
26.86,3.14,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
25.28,5,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
14.73,2.2,Female,No,Sat,Dinner,2
10.51,1.25,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
17.92,3.08,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
44.3,2.5,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,3
22.42,3.48,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
20.92,4.08,Female,No,Sat,Dinner,2
15.36,1.64,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
20.49,4.06,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
25.21,4.29,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
18.24,3.76,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
14.31,4,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
14,3,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
7.25,1,Female,No,Sat,Dinner,1
10.59,1.61,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
10.63,2,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
50.81,10,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,3
15.81,3.16,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
26.59,3.41,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,3
38.73,3,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,4
24.27,2.03,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
12.76,2.23,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
30.06,2,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,3
25.89,5.16,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,4
48.33,9,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,4
13.27,2.5,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
28.17,6.5,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,3
12.9,1.1,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
28.15,3,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,5
11.59,1.5,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
7.74,1.44,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
30.14,3.09,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,4
20.45,3,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,4
13.28,2.72,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
22.12,2.88,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
24.01,2,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,4
15.69,3,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,3
11.61,3.39,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
10.77,1.47,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
15.53,3,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
10.07,1.25,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
12.6,1,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
32.83,1.17,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
35.83,4.67,Female,No,Sat,Dinner,3
29.03,5.92,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,3
27.18,2,Female,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
22.67,2,Male,Yes,Sat,Dinner,2
17.82,1.75,Male,No,Sat,Dinner,2
```

`tips-sun.csv`:

```
totalbill,tip,sex,smoker,day,time,size
16.99,1.01,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,2
10.34,1.66,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,3
21.01,3.5,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,3
23.68,3.31,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
24.59,3.61,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,4
25.29,4.71,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,4
8.77,2,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
26.88,3.12,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,4
15.04,1.96,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
14.78,3.23,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
10.27,1.71,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
35.26,5,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,4
15.42,1.57,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
18.43,3,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,4
14.83,3.02,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,2
21.58,3.92,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
10.33,1.67,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,3
16.29,3.71,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,3
16.97,3.5,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,3
17.46,2.54,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
13.94,3.06,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
9.68,1.32,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
30.4,5.6,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,4
18.29,3,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
22.23,5,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
32.4,6,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,4
28.55,2.05,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,3
18.04,3,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
12.54,2.5,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
10.29,2.6,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,2
34.81,5.2,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,4
9.94,1.56,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
25.56,4.34,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,4
19.49,3.51,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
38.07,4,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,3
23.95,2.55,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
25.71,4,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,3
17.31,3.5,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,2
29.93,5.07,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,4
14.07,2.5,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
13.13,2,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
17.26,2.74,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,3
24.55,2,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,4
19.77,2,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,4
29.85,5.14,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,5
48.17,5,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,6
25,3.75,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,4
13.39,2.61,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,2
16.49,2,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,4
21.5,3.5,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,4
12.66,2.5,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
16.21,2,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,3
13.81,2,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
17.51,3,Female,Yes,Sun,Dinner,2
24.52,3.48,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,3
20.76,2.24,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,2
31.71,4.5,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,4
7.25,5.15,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,2
31.85,3.18,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,2
16.82,4,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,2
32.9,3.11,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,2
17.89,2,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,2
14.48,2,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,2
9.6,4,Female,Yes,Sun,Dinner,2
34.63,3.55,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,2
34.65,3.68,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,4
23.33,5.65,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,2
45.35,3.5,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,3
23.17,6.5,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,4
40.55,3,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,2
20.69,5,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,5
20.9,3.5,Female,Yes,Sun,Dinner,3
30.46,2,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,5
18.15,3.5,Female,Yes,Sun,Dinner,3
23.1,4,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,3
15.69,1.5,Male,Yes,Sun,Dinner,2
```

`tips-thur.csv`:

```
totalbill,tip,sex,smoker,day,time,size
27.2,4,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,4
22.76,3,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
17.29,2.71,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
19.44,3,Male,Yes,Thur,Lunch,2
16.66,3.4,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
10.07,1.83,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,1
32.68,5,Male,Yes,Thur,Lunch,2
15.98,2.03,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
34.83,5.17,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,4
13.03,2,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
18.28,4,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
24.71,5.85,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
21.16,3,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
10.65,1.5,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
12.43,1.8,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
24.08,2.92,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,4
11.69,2.31,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
13.42,1.68,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
14.26,2.5,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
15.95,2,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
12.48,2.52,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
29.8,4.2,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,6
8.52,1.48,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
14.52,2,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
11.38,2,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
22.82,2.18,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,3
19.08,1.5,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
20.27,2.83,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
11.17,1.5,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
12.26,2,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
18.26,3.25,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
8.51,1.25,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
10.33,2,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
14.15,2,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
16,2,Male,Yes,Thur,Lunch,2
13.16,2.75,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
17.47,3.5,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
34.3,6.7,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,6
41.19,5,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,5
27.05,5,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,6
16.43,2.3,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
8.35,1.5,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
18.64,1.36,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,3
11.87,1.63,Female,No,Thur,Lunch,2
9.78,1.73,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
7.51,2,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
19.81,4.19,Female,Yes,Thur,Lunch,2
28.44,2.56,Male,Yes,Thur,Lunch,2
15.48,2.02,Male,Yes,Thur,Lunch,2
16.58,4,Male,Yes,Thur,Lunch,2
7.56,1.44,Male,No,Thur,Lunch,2
10.34,2,Male,Yes,Thur,Lunch,2
43.11,5,Female,Yes,Thur,Lunch,4
13,2,Female,Yes,Thur,Lunch,2
13.51,2,Male,Yes,Thur,Lunch,2
18.71,4,Male,Yes,Thur,Lunch,3
12.74,2.01,Female,Yes,Thur,Lunch,2
13,2,Female,Yes,Thur,Lunch,2
16.4,2.5,Female,Yes,Thur,Lunch,2
20.53,4,Male,Yes,Thur,Lunch,4
16.47,3.23,Female,Yes,Thur,Lunch,3
18.78,3,Female,No,Thur,Dinner,2
```

Here is my best attempt and the output

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={group size=2 by 2},
        ymin=0,ymax=0.75,]
    \nextgroupplot[title=Friday]
    \addplot+[only marks,mark=o] table [x=totalbill,y expr={\thisrow{tip} / \thisrow{totalbill}},col sep=comma]
        {tips-fri.csv};
    \nextgroupplot[title=Saturday]
    \addplot+[only marks,mark=o] table [x=totalbill,y expr={\thisrow{tip} / \thisrow{totalbill}},col sep=comma]
        {tips-sat.csv};
    \nextgroupplot[title=Sunday]
    \addplot+[only marks,mark=o] table [x=totalbill,y expr={\thisrow{tip} / \thisrow{totalbill}},col sep=comma]
        {tips-sun.csv};
    \nextgroupplot[title=Thursday]
    \addplot+[only marks,mark=o] table [x=totalbill,y expr={\thisrow{tip} / \thisrow{totalbill}},col sep=comma]
        {tips-thur.csv};
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Room for improvement**

- How to get the title of each plot closer to the corresponding plot?
- How to put the title in a grey rectangular box above the corresponding plot?
- How to insert the x-axis and y-axis labels?
- I **don't** need the background of the plot area to be shaded grey, nor to have help lines.

Comment: If you really want to use LaTeX to replicate this graph, why not try TikzDevice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I used random numbers because I was too lazy to save your four data files.) Here a suggestion that gives

[image]

Your first two requirements can be achieved by changing the `title style`. This actually appends the options you define to the node creating the title. Adding some negative `yshift` moves it closer to the axis, `fill`ing it adds the background color. You only need to make sure the width is the same as the width of the axis, so set the `minimum width` of the title node to the same as the axis `width`, with `scale only axis` enabled:

```
width=\myaxiswidth,
scale only axis,
title style={
   yshift=-6pt,
   fill=black!10,
   minimum width=\myaxiswidth},
```

Here `\myaxiswidth` is defined by `\newcommand\myaxiswidth{4cm}`.

The axis labels can be placed relative to the subplots. Each axis will be given the name `group cMrN`, where `M` and `N` are column and row number, respectively. Using the `calc` library, the mid point between the e.g. the lower left corner of the top left plot, and the upper left corner of the lower left plot is calculated, and a node placed relative to this. Similar for the other axis:

```
\node [left=.7cm,anchor=south,rotate=90] at ($(group c1r1.south west)!0.5!(group c1r2.north west)$) {$x$-axis label};
\node [below=.6cm] at ($(group c1r2.south east)!0.5!(group c2r2.south west)$) {$y$-axis label};
```

These are placed outside the `groupplot`, inside the `tikzpicture`.

The `group style` is changed to

```
group style={
      group size=2 by 2,
      x descriptions at=edge bottom,
      y descriptions at=edge left,
      horizontal sep=2pt,
      vertical sep=20pt},
```

to get xticks only on the bottom, and yticks only on the left, and to improve the spacing.  Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\newcommand\myaxiswidth{4cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=2 by 2,
            x descriptions at=edge bottom,
            y descriptions at=edge left,
            horizontal sep=2pt,
            vertical sep=20pt},
         ymin=0,ymax=0.75,
         width=\myaxiswidth,
         scale only axis,
         title style={
            yshift=-6pt,
            fill=black!10,
            minimum width=\myaxiswidth},
         domain=0:45, %just for example
         samples=20 %just for example
         ]
    \nextgroupplot[title=Friday]
    \addplot[only marks,mark=o] {rnd};
    \nextgroupplot[title=Saturday]
    \addplot[only marks,mark=o] {rnd};
    \nextgroupplot[title=Sunday]
    \addplot[only marks,mark=o] {rnd};
    \nextgroupplot[title=Thursday]
    \addplot[only marks,mark=o] {rnd};
    \end{groupplot}

    \node [left=.7cm,anchor=south,rotate=90] at ($(group c1r1.south west)!0.5!(group c1r2.north west)$) {$x$-axis label};
   \node [below=.6cm] at ($(group c1r2.south east)!0.5!(group c2r2.south west)$) {$y$-axis label};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```